# Selenium Web Driver executeScript Showing error: [JavascriptError: missing ) after argument list] name: 'JavascriptError'

Tags: jquery, node.js, selenium

```
return driver.executeScript("\
    console.log('Wrong sadmasdaskdka1sdkakdk');\
    $('option:selected', 'select[name='who']').removeAttr('selected');\
    $('select[name='who']').find('option[value='2']').attr('selected',true);\
")
```

`console.log` is well printing but when selector comes to action it show error and throw it to catch block and show this error :

> { [JavascriptError: missing ) after argument list] name: 'JavascriptError' }

Answer (score 0):

The issue is in the statements like `$('option:selected', 'select[name='who']')`

Make sure you close the quotes you are opening, in this case it gets confused.
You should use something like:
`$("option:selected", "select[name='who']")`

The same for the next one, include single quotes in double quotes or vice versa and don not use the same quotes inside and outside.

I see that you already have double quotes for the entire string so you could try also something like:
`$('option:selected', 'select[name=who]')` 
meaning to remove the single quotes from parts like `select[name='who']` and to use without them like `select[name=who]`

Comment: hi  thanks but it's now showing another error :
{ [JavascriptError: $(...) is null] name: 'JavascriptError' }
can you please help me

Comment: It seems that it doesn't find the element. Use a regular wait for the element and after this execute the script.Also first test the script in the browser to fix any issues and to be sure that is working.

Comment: i used console as well but it's showing same error... i tried same thing in different website but it's working

Comment: identify the line where it fails, and check the selectors manually and see if they are ok or if they need update.